# Google Analytics - Language of the first session of an user

Tags: filter, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-filters, dialect

[image]This is related to the language of a website like FB, amazon, booking, etc.

When you open one of this sites, or when you click on the search and goes to the site, it opens with a language by default.

There is custom dimension (Cd-session- diatect, or something like that) that is the langueage of the site, but is the last one you had in your session. Would anyone know what is the custom dimensions in Google analytics to filter by this "first visit"? I heard there is something to filter by the first time you visit the site but I cannot find it.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

A custom dimension, by definition, does not exist by default. So you should create a custom dimension like the one you are already looking at but **with hit scope instead of session**.

In this way you can see which language of the site was active on the landing page, which is the first page of each session.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.    There is Dimension called "cd-session-language-dialect", which is the language of the website.   So you are saying that on this dimension, I have to create a "hit scope" instead of session, right?  Sorry I am new to google analytics. Is a "hit scope" a name of a filter itself?     I see you mention Landing pages. Would this work if you directly add "Amazon.com" (For example) in the browser?

Comment: Custom dimension is not a filter, you can configure it at Property level in Administration panel. You can choose hit, session or user scope. Landing page is the first page of a session, the pages through which visitors entered your site. What you mean with: directly add "Amazon.com" in the browser?

Comment: Sorry I am not web analyst so I might be very clear.  
**For example**, I wanna measure traffic when booking.com opes with language(flag on b.ocm) with es-es by deafault.      *
*How you can get to booking.com?**   1) google ads, 2)organic seachs in google, 3)you type in the browers booking.com etc.      
**Issue:**  when you are in booking.com already you can change the language flag mny times. Therefore for my purpuse I need to filter by the first time the broswer opens.     
Would this make sense?  :)

Comment: What you ask, if I understand correctly, is not possible unless you manage the analytics of booking.com, amazon, etc ... You can't track the statistics of other website.

Comment: I do. I am just being vage on sharing my company name. Since I can, how would it be? :)

Comment: In this case you must configure the custom dimension described on the hit level on booking.com analytics (and in analytics of Amazon, FB, ecc...) and pass the information to it with the Google Analytics hit. Then in Analytics you query landing page and custom dimension.

Comment: Sorry, what you say to do, is it all in Google analytics?  so not querying in somewhere else as BigQuery, right? Saying this as I have just access to Google Analytics. Thanks a mil!

Comment: Even in BigQuery if the data has been exported.

Comment: I mean if you would know how to do this one Google Analytics sorry, as I just have access to it...

Comment: As I wrote above. With "query" I meant to query the Landing page report.

Comment: Sorry but it is not clear. Would you mean the way I am doing in the pic attached in my first coment? if so, would you know how I would need to create this specifically? thanks agian for the help

Comment: Yes, but you need the hit level custom dimension to add as secondary dimension and to see on the landing page what the user's language was. You have to configure it, on the site or in Tag Manager (if there is one), it is not something that can be explained in a comment.

Comment: Updated the above pic.  cd-session-language-dialect is supposed to be the language of the multilingue websites. i.e. in booking.com is the flag that you can use to change the language of the site.

Comment: If it is at the session level, it does not mean that it is the language set when it was on the landing page, but the last language set in the session.